# Select matches based on the value of another column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a `dataframe` with company matches and I want to extract certain rows(matches)

my input

```
df <- data.frame(company_us=
c("apple","google","netflix","apple","netflix","google"),
                company_eu = c("nokia","vodafone","sky","sky","nokia","vodafone"),
                difference = c(5,5,5,10,10,10)
       )

#the df

company_us company_eu difference
1      apple      nokia          5
2     google   vodafone          5
3    netflix        sky          5
4      apple        sky         10
5    netflix      nokia         10
6     google   vodafone         10
```

For each `company_us` find the pairs, here for `apple` it would be `apple nokia` and `apple sky`
I want to select only the match with the smallest `difference`.
In this case the row `apple,nokia,5`

the output I want is:

```
 company_us company_eu difference
1      apple      nokia          5
2     google   vodafone          5
3    netflix        sky          5
```

I have no Idea how to go about this problem. If anyone could recommend literature or something else on how to tackle a problem like this I would be very grateful!

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr` you can use the [`slice_min()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/slice.html) function to retrieve the minimum value of a variable inside a group

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(company_us) %>% 
  slice_min(difference)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   company_us [3]
  company_us company_eu difference
  <chr>      <chr>           <dbl>
1 apple      nokia               5
2 google     vodafone            5
3 netflix    sky                 5
```

Since you seem lacking some knowledge about operations within groups of data, I leave you this [link](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_by.html) with some examples of applications of the `group_by()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ave` from `base R`

```
df[with(df, difference == ave(difference, company_us, FUN = min)),]
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` option using ´which.min`

```
> setDT(df)[, .SD[which.min(difference)], company_us]
   company_us company_eu difference
1:      apple      nokia          5
2:     google   vodafone          5
3:    netflix        sky          5
```